# Sort a multidimensional associative array by a column and preserve first level keys

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array that looks like this:

```
$this->wordswithdata = [
    'team1' => [
        'points' => 10,
        'players' => [],
    ],
    'team2' => [
        'points' => 23,
        'players' => []
    ]
];
```

and I would like to sort the teams by the number of points each team has from highest to lowest. I have tried this:

```
function sort_by_points($a,$b)
{
    if ($a['points'] == $b['points']) return 0;
        return ($a['points'] < $b['points']) ? 1 : -1;
}

usort($this->wordswithdata, "sortbycount");
```

But that approach overrides the keys containing the teamnames and returns:

```
[
    0 => [
        'points' => 23,
        'players' => []
    ],
    1 => [
        'points' => 10,
        'players' => [],
    ]
]
```

Is there any way to sort the array without losing the teamnames as the array keys?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use the [uasort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) function, that should keep the key => value associations intact.

(side note: you can do `return $a['points'] - $b['points']` instead of the ifs, or as of php7 the [spacehsip `<=>` operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), thx mbomb007 for the update)

Comment: As of PHP 7, you can use the spaceship operator `<=>` instead of subtracting. [See this related question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44309755/2415524)

Answer (score 28):

You can use [`uasort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php):

```
uasort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['points'] - $b['points'];
});
```

> This function sorts an array such that array indices **maintain their correlation** with the array elements they are associated with, using a user-defined comparison function.

Answer (score 2):

U can sort an Associative array by its value like this

```
$age = array("Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"43");

function Ascending($a, $b) {   
    if ($a == $b) {        
        return 0;
    }   
        return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1; 
}  

function Descending($a, $b) {   
    if ($a == $b) {        
        return 0;
    }   
        return ($a > $b) ? -1 : 1; 
}  


echo "Ascending order" ;
uasort($age,"Ascending");
print_r($age);


echo "</br>Descending order" ;
uasort($age,"Descending");
print_r($age);
```

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, this page should include an approach using `array_multisort()` -- this function will preserve non-numeric keys by default.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/3LVMa))

```
array_multisort(
    array_column($array, 'points'),
    SORT_DESC,
    $array
);
```

---

That said, there is nothing wrong with calling `uasort()` with the spaceship operator. Note that `$b` data is on the left side of the three-way comparison operator and `$a` is on the right side to achieve descending sorting.

Code: [Demo](https://3v4l.org/J3kuG)

```
uasort(
    $array,
    fn($a, $b) => $b['points'] <=> $a['points']
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code hope it will work.

```
function aasort (&$array, $key) {
    $sorter=array();
    $ret=array();
    reset($array);
    foreach ($array as $ii => $va) {
        $sorter[$ii]=$va[$key];
    }
    asort($sorter);
    foreach ($sorter as $ii => $va) {
        $ret[$ii]=$array[$ii];
    }
    $array=$ret;
}

aasort($your_array,"points");
```

Comment: I don't see any compelling reason for anyone to use this unexplained and indirect answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
its working fine i giving example
that array need sort
$sumarray=array [▼
  484 => 54.7875
  486 => 53.5375
  487 => 52.9125
  488 => 52.2875
  493 => 54.7875
]

$original=$sumarray;

 $svalue=array_values($sumarray);
  rsort($svalue);
  $sorted=array();
  foreach ($svalue as $key => $value) {
   $kk=array_search($value,$sumarray);
  $sorted[$kk]=$value;
  unset($sumarray[$kk]);

    }
  print_r($original);
    print_r($svalue);
  print_r($sorted);
             //out put
  array:5 [▼
  484 => 54.7875
  486 => 53.5375
  487 => 52.9125
  488 => 52.2875
  493 => 54.7875
]
array:5 [▼
  0 => 54.7875
  1 => 54.7875
  2 => 53.5375
  3 => 52.9125
  4 => 52.2875
]
array:5 [▼
  484 => 54.7875
  493 => 54.7875
  486 => 53.5375
  487 => 52.9125
  488 => 52.2875
]
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: I cannot fathom any possible scenario where I would want to invite this kind of indirect/convoluted code into my project.  Outside of the fact that this answer ignored the same data structure, why should anyone with a flat associative array call `array_values()`, then `rsort()`, then make iterated calls of `array_search()` and `unset()`???